# Transformation Matrix for Derivative

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

[image]

I have figured out how to show Part A by using properties of derivatives.
For Part B, we know that $T(f)$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 4a+2b+c\\4a+b\\2a\end{pmatrix}$, so when asked to find a matrix $A$, would it have to be the case that when $A$ is multiplied by the $3*1$ matrix $[f]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\x\\x^2\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Note that $x $ is not in $ \mathbb{R}$, and so  $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ x^2 \end{pmatrix} $ is not in $\mathbb{R}^3$, However your $T(f)$  which is equal to  $A[f]_B$ should be in  $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
Use the fact that  $T$ is linear, and that if we take  $B=(1,x,x^2)=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, then any $f$ can be written as  $$f= ab_1+bb_2+cb_3= \begin{bmatrix}  b_1  \quad b_2 \quad b_3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b  \\ c  \end{bmatrix} $$
Then $$ f'=\cdots =\begin{bmatrix}  \cdots  \quad \cdots  \quad \cdots \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b  \\ c  \end{bmatrix}  $$
and  $$f''=\cdots =\begin{bmatrix}  \cdots  \quad \cdots  \quad \cdots \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b  \\ c  \end{bmatrix}  $$
Thus $A=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

I assume $f(x) = a x^2 + b x + c$ and
$$
[f]_B = [a x^2 + b x + c]_B = (a, b, c)^t
$$
and the task is finding $A$ such that
$$
A [f]_B = A (a, b, c)^t \overset{!}{=} T(f) = (4a+2b+c,4a+b,2a)^t
$$
Another choice could be
$$
[f]_B = [a x^2 + b x + c]_B = (c, b, a)^t
$$
so please check your definition of $[.]_B$.